# why won't my text display from on ViewController to the next

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel

I am trying to pass the String property I have to set the text of the Label. However, the string won't display. Im going through multiple View Controllers. The Idea is to take the information from a textField and then store that into a property. Then set Labels to the string property in later View controllers

```
SentenceViewContoller.m
    #import "SentenceViewController.h"
    #import "DrawViewController.h"

    @interface SentenceViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation SentenceViewController

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
         self.Sentence1TF.text = self.Sent1Str;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {

    }


    - (IBAction)stopped:(id)sender {
    }
    @end
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
SentenceViewController.m
    #import "SentenceViewController.h"
    #import "DrawViewController.h"

    @interface SentenceViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation SentenceViewController

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
         self.Sentence1TF.text = self.Sent1Str;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {

    }


    - (IBAction)stopped:(id)sender {
    }
    @end
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DrawViewController.h

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface DrawViewController : UIViewController {

    CGPoint lastPoint;
    CGFloat red;
    CGFloat green;
    CGFloat blue;
    CGFloat brush;
    CGFloat opacity;
    BOOL mouseSwiped;
    }

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *tempDrawImage;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *mainImage;
    - (IBAction)pencilPressed:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)eraserPressed:(id)sender;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Sentence1;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Done;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Sent1Str;


    @end
------------------------------------------------------------------------
DrawViewController.m

    #import "DrawViewController.h"       
    #import "Draw2ViewController.h"
    #import "SentenceViewController.h"

    @interface DrawViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation DrawViewController

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        red = 0.0/255.0;
        green = 0.0/255.0;
        blue = 0.0/255.0;
        brush = 10.0;
        opacity = 1.0;

        [super viewDidLoad];
        //Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.Sent1Str = ((SentenceViewController *)self.parentViewController).Sent1Str;
        Draw2ViewController *D2V = [[Draw2ViewController alloc] init];
        D2V.myImage = _mainImage;

        self.Sentence1.text = self.Sent1Str;
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (IBAction)pencilPressed:(id)sender {
        UIButton * PressedButton = (UIButton*)sender;

        switch(PressedButton.tag)
        {
            case 0:
                red = 0.0/255.0;
                green = 0.0/255.0;
                blue = 0.0/255.0;
                break;
            case 1:
                red = 105.0/255.0;
                green = 105.0/255.0;
                blue = 105.0/255.0;
                break;
            case 2:
                red = 255.0/255.0;
                green = 0.0/255.0;
                blue = 0.0/255.0;
                break;
            case 3:
                red = 0.0/255.0;
                green = 0.0/255.0;
                blue = 255.0/255.0;
                break;
            case 4:
                red = 102.0/255.0;
                green = 204.0/255.0;
                blue = 0.0/255.0;
                break;
            case 5:
                red = 102.0/255.0;
                green = 255.0/255.0;
                blue = 0.0/255.0;
                break;
            case 6:
                red = 51.0/255.0;
                green = 204.0/255.0;
                blue = 255.0/255.0;
                break;
            case 7:
                red = 160.0/255.0;
                green = 82.0/255.0;
                blue = 45.0/255.0;
                break;
            case 8:
                red = 255.0/255.0;
                green = 102.0/255.0;
                blue = 0.0/255.0;
                break;
            case 9:
                red = 255.0/255.0;
                green = 255.0/255.0;
                blue = 0.0/255.0;
                break;
        }



    }

    - (IBAction)eraserPressed:(id)sender {

        red = 255.0/255.0;
        green = 255.0/255.0;
        blue = 255.0/255.0;
        opacity = 1.0;
    }
    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        mouseSwiped = NO;
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    }

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        mouseSwiped = YES;
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        [self.tempDrawImage setAlpha:opacity];
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        lastPoint = currentPoint;
    }

    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        if(!mouseSwiped) {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
            [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
            CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush);
            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, opacity);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
            CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
            CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
            self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage.frame.size);
        [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
        [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:opacity];
        self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        self.tempDrawImage.image = nil;
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {

    }



    @end

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Draw2ViewController.h

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "DrawViewController.h"
    #import "ResultsViewController.h"

    @interface Draw2ViewController : UIViewController
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *Draw2Image;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *myImage;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *Sentence2TF;
    - (IBAction)stopped2:(id)sender;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Sent1Str;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Sent2Str;

    @end
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Draw2ViewController.m

    #import "Draw2ViewController.h"
    #import "DrawViewController.h"
    #import "ResultsViewController.h"

    @interface Draw2ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation Draw2ViewController

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        _Sentence2TF.text = _Sent2Str;
         self.Sent1Str = ((DrawViewController *)self.parentViewController).Sent1Str;

     }

     - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
     }
     - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {

    }



    - (IBAction)stopped2:(id)sender {
    }
    @end
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResultsViewController.h

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ResultsViewController : UIViewController
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ResultsImage;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Sent1Results;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Sent2Results;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Sent2Str;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Sent1Str;

    @end
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResultsViewController.m

    #import "ResultsViewController.h"
    #import "Draw2ViewController.h"

    @interface ResultsViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ResultsViewController

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization

        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
         self.Sent1Str = ((Draw2ViewController *)self.parentViewController).Sent1Str;
         self.Sent2Str = ((Draw2ViewController *)self.parentViewController).Sent2Str;
        _Sent1Results.text = _Sent1Str;
        _Sent2Results.text = _Sent2Str;
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @end
```

Comment: Have you logged self.parentViewController in any of these controllers to see if it's non-nil? And please, when you post code, edit it to show only the relevant information. There's certainly no need to post all that boilerplate code.

Comment: It Does come up with nil, but I don't know why its not getting the data

Comment: What does your view controller hierarchy look like? Are you using a UINavigationController? How are you moving from one view controller to the next?

Comment: Well, if self.parentViewController is nil, then the string will be nil also. Using parentViewController may not be appropriate depending on your controller hierarchy. You need to say how you're going from one controller to the next.

Comment: Im moving from one viewcontroller to the next through a button clicked segue.